# Java creating new objects and naming them from a collection

Tags: java, arrays, object, collections

Im trying to do something in my project but it would be hard to explain so I thought of an example. Let's say you have an Array of String Student names called studentArray. Now you have a class called Student(String name). Now in your Attendance class, you have a method where you want to load an ArrayList of Student Objects; let's call this ArrayList classRoom. But you have to create create these Student objects first, which you do by Student (arbitrary name) = new Student(); . Now you want your reference name to these Student objects as random Strings already loaded into an Array called randomStrings. Now:

```
for(int i =0; i<=studentArray.size(); i++)
{
       Student (arbitrary name) = new Student(studentArray[i]);
       classRoom.add(THE STUDENT THAT WAS JUST CREATED);
}
```

Now I wanted use the arbitrary name as randomStrings[i]. But I'm wondering, is something like this possible in java? How would I do something like that?

```
Student randomStrings[i] = new Student(studentArray[i]);
```

isn't something they let me do. I hope you guys can understand my example because I have no idea how else to illustrate it.

P.S.

like:

```
   Student letter0 = new Student(studentArray[i]); //letter0 is the string in randomString array
   Student letter1 = new Student(studentArray[i+1]); //letter1 is the string in randomString array
   Student letter2 = new Student(studentArray[i+2]); //letter2 is the string in randomString array
   Student letter3 = new Student(studentArray[i+3]); //letter3 is the string in randomString array
```

instead of doing all that, I wanted to just pull the name from the array randomString and let the loop create the Student objects for me itself without me manually doing it. I hope it's clearer.

Comment: Basically you want to initialize an array of `Student` instances, each one with a different student name picked from an array of random `String`s?

Comment: So you want to create a variable that its name is `randomStrings[i]`?

Comment: I want to create a variable who's name is the String at position i of randomStrings array.

Comment: Like if I wanted to be lazy, and instead of typing all the reference names for the newly created Student objects, I want the machine to do it by using the Strings from the array.

Comment: Trust me there is no reason you would want to do this, not in any sane  reality that I have experience anyway.

Comment: Since you shouldn't care about the names of your program's variables at runtime, I'll assume you want this for some output that (ultimately) humans will read.  You can create an instance variable on `Student` to hold this human-readable value.  Or use a class that implements `java.util.Map` to manage the association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What you want to do is a bad idea why you want to do it is more concerning:

This is what you actually want to do:

```
classRoom.add(new Student(studentArray[i]));
```

then make sure that you can do the reverse:

```
classRoom.getStudentByName(final String name);
```

Where you have:

```
public class ClassRoom 
{
    private final Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();

    public void add(final Student s) { this.students.put(s.getName(), s); }

    public Student getStudentByName(final String n) { return this.students.get(n); }    
}
```

And you store/retrieve your students in this `Map` instance.

*The languages that do allow this prove that here is no valid reason for trying to create name references dynamically, it is impossible to debug and reason about when things are created dynamically like this from looking at static code.*

#### A good example is `metadata` programming in Python or Javascript.

> You can programmatically add data and function members to objects in
> both languages, doing so in very specific limited cases in extreme
> moderation can be powerful and elegant.
>
> Abusing it creates unmaintainable indecipherable mess that can't be
> understood or reasoned about by just reading the code, it demands a
> powerful feature rich step debugger and an extremely patient person to
> try and work with the code.
>
> Now just imagine if you could create named variables in local scopes
> willy nilly it would be total chaos and completely non-deterministic
> to a human reading the code.

That said in my 17 years of working with Java, I have seen many misguided attempts to do what you want, probably because of the same reason, naivete and lack of practical knowledge and experience, they were all nightmare scenarios for maintainers and made me lots of money as a consultant hired to fix the mess that had been made. This is **not** a solution to any problem, if it was it would be supported by pretty much every language and it isn't.

One such solution generated the source code, wrote it out to the file system and then compiled it and loaded the resulting bytecode back in with a custom classloader, the entire system was infected with this mess, it was a nightmare of reflection abuse as well, it was truly a catastrophic WTF of the most extreme magnitude.

Comment: So professional coders, when having to create mass amounts of objects with very similar reference names, such as letter1, letter2, letter3, etc.; they do so manually? They just do Object letter1 = new Object(); ---Object letter2 = new Object(); etc?

Comment: No an experienced developer would never even conceive of doing anything this way, if you are doing that you are doing it wrong. You should `NEVER` care what your variable names are at runtime, they are converted into opaque tokens by the compiler anyway.Plain and simple, if you need lots of object references you use a `Map`.

Comment: So, someone at sometime had to hardcode all this data manually correct? And thank you for the very insightful response.

Comment: **NO** no one ever ***that knew what they were doing*** would ever concieve doing anything like this, it is not an idiom of any sort, it reeks of [TheDailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Alumni-Variables.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to take some strings that are stored in an array and use them as variable names for a class i.e., identifier of the variable. I don't think it is possible because identifier is not a class object it is a token you have to name your identifier manually or use any data structure. If it is sequential, as in the example, you can use an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to do that.

```
Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();
students.put("Enrique", new Student("Enrique"));
```

OR

```
Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();
for(String randomString : randomStrings){
    students.put(randomString, new Student(randomString));
}
```

And then to use

```
doSomethingWithAStudent(students.get("Enriqué"));
```

**BUT** accessing from a `Map` is slower than accessing a variable directly and can be a bit clunky in some scenarios.  Don't do it just cause you don't want to write variables.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you misunderstood my question, but that's because my example was very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying too hard.  All you need is:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= studentArray.size(); i++)  {
    Student  student = new Student(studentArray[i]);
    classRoom.add( student );
}
```

There's no need to use a different local variable for each student.  In this case the `student` variable gets recreated each time you go through the loop, so it's different each time.  Even if you declared it outside the loop, it would be reinitialized each time, so it would work just as well.  And you could rewrite this as:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= studentArray.size(); i++)
    classRoom.add( new Student( studentArray[i] );
```

though you might want to stick with the first way until you get the hang of it.

Generally, if you find yourself creating series of variables with names like x1, x2, x3, ...., xn, you want to put the values directly into an array or collection or something instead.

Comment: No, my example sucks, that's why it seems as though I'm trying too hard. But thank you anyway.